# Always charge the most expensive flat rate shipping in an order

Tags: commerce, 9

I have a Drupal Commerce site with two product types. One has free shipping, and the other costs € 3,-. When both products are in the cart, the customer is allowed to choose either of those rates, which is not what I want.

I want to disable the free shipping rate when the second product type is in the shopping cart. On shipping calculation the most expensive shipping should be calculated.

In shipping conditions, there is no way to set separate rules for two product types, to negate a product type or to use an AND operator on product types.

I found answers for Drupal 7, but Drupal Commerce for Drupal 8/9 is completely different.